# Tkinter program won't stop running properly after calling PySimpleGUI function

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

my program won't stop running after clicking Close on the window. It's always showing "You program is still running! Do you want to kill it?" when try to close IDLE. But it works fine when comment out the sg.popup("sg Popup") line. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup("sg Popup")  #comment this line then works fine

root = Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.geometry("320x240")
a = Label(root, text ="Hello World!!", font=16)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you need to use both GUI toolkits

Comment: There's already one `Tk()` exists after you call `sg.popup()`, not sure if it work for you with `sg.Window.hidden_master_root.destroy()` before you call `root = Tk()`.